# SVG icons in HTML: what difference does the initial resolution make?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

Google published [Material Design Icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) in two different resolutions of SVG:

> SVG versions of all icons in both 24px and 48px flavours. [...] Decide
>   on the icon resolution required for your project and copy, then
>   reference the icons you wish to use.

What's the difference, if they are in *Scalable Vector Graphics*? Shouldn't 24px SVG work as well as 48px SVG on any screen resolution? If so, why / when would I want to put larger icons in my [SVG sprite](http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.  As long as the icons are identical, it shouldn't really matter.

However the two sizes are not identical.  The smaller version of some icons has been tweaked for legibility.  For instance, compare the 18px and 48px version of the "justify" icon.  One has four lines, the other has five.

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/editor/svg/production/ic_format_align_justify_18px.svg

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/editor/svg/production/ic_format_align_justify_48px.svg